# Fetching the RTF field value

Tags: apex, soql, metadata

Using `Schema.DisplayType` we are  able to fetch the field type i.e RTF. can anyone help me how to fetch the value present in that field.

```
String type='case';
Map<String, Schema.SObjectType> schemaMap = Schema.getGlobalDescribe();
Schema.SObjectType schemaTyp = schemaMap.get(type);
Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> fieldMap = schemaTyp.getDescribe().fields.getMap();      
Schema.DisplayType myType=fieldMap.get('RichTextField__c').getDescribe().getType();
```

Answer (score 0):

You named example of working with metadata. Data, that describes data.

to get value of a field for concrete record, use SOQL query:

```
Id caseId = 'some known case id';
Case selectedCase = [
    select Id, RichTextField__c
    from Case
    where Id =:caseId
    limit 1
    ];
System.debug(selectedCase.RichTextField__c);
```